# Do I need to do something special in the ASP.NET MVC app to read a Json response from a Web API 2 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Is there something special I need to define in an ASP.NET MVC application to read an incoming response from a ASP.NET Web API?

From my MVC app, I make a request to an ASP.NET Web API using `System.Net.HttpClient`. The API receives the request and processes it fine and returns a valid response. However, the MVC application, it appears, never gets the response. I have a break point on the line that makes the request. The flow of control never comes back after executing that line. The MVC app just keeps waiting and times-out after a very long time.

However, I can confirm that the API returns a valid Json response. I have tried composing this request in Chrome Postman and see that the API returns a valid response.

Here's the code from my MVC app that makes the request to the Web API:

```
public async Task<R> PostAsJsonAsync<T, R>(string uri, T value)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUri);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, value);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<R>();
        else return default(R);
    }
}
```

In the past, i.e. before Web API 2, I've had MVC apps talk to the Web API without any problem. I don't know if I am missing something that has been introduced in Web API 2.

Comment: Are you sure your WebAPI application receives this request? If you say there is timeout, maybe there is something wrong with your URL. Can you attach to your WebAPI application and set breakpoint in the destination method? Is it hitted?

Comment: Yes, the Web API receives the request and processes it correctly and returns a valid JSON response. I have set breakpoints and also seen the response with Chrome Postman, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: In fact, it seems you do everything correctly... I would double-check whether your service receives your request. You may provide Chrome Postman with correct URL while here in code you have another. You can also try, for example, Fiddler or Wireshark and see where you request actually goes and what is in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you are getting a deadlock. Are you using `.Result` anywhere? You should be using `async` all the way. I mean your MVC action method should also be `async` method and they should `await` and not use `.Result`. Read this log post by  Stephen Cleary for more info. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html